# How can I display a list of leads in a Visualforce pageBlockTable?

Tags: visualforce, controller, leads, pageblocktable

Following the Visualforce example [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_access_data.htm), I can display the list of account names in a pageblocktable but changing the controller to Lead does not display the list of lead names.  Why not?  It works great with the Contact controller as well, but not the Lead controller.

According to [this page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm), the Lead controller is also a type of standard list controller and it seems this simple thing should work.  What am I missing?

Here's the complete source of the page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" recordSetVar="leads" tabstyle="lead" sidebar="false">
   <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leads}" var="ld">
      <apex:column value="{!ld.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your source code?

Comment: this might be an issue with object permission, pls check it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the Account example from your first link, and changed each Account reference to lead.

**EDIT**: From the [doc page you link above](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_access_data.htm), "This page does not specify a filter in the request, so the page is displayed with the last used filter."  In my testing, my last used Lead filter happened to be "All Open Leads".  If your last used filter shows no leads (e.g., "My Leads" if you don't own any leads), then the standard controller won't load any records by default.  I've updated the code to show a List View dropdown for the standard controller using code from [this doc page on using list views with standard controllers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_list_views.htm).

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" tabstyle="account" sidebar="false">
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:form >
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:outputLabel value="View:"/>
        <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="list"/>
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:panelGrid>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" id="list">
        <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Note the use of `apex:actionSupport` to update the list in real time using the `rerender` param, and the addition of a matching `id` on the pageBlockTable for the `rerender` to reference.

Comment: Your code is identical to mine.  There is no other code in the Visualforce page I'm working with.  To be absolutely sure, I've copied your code and replaced my own with it but am seeing the same issue.  What could be causing the issue?

Comment: What is displayed?  Can you post a screen shot?  Also (silly as it sounds) - try in another browser?  If you have development mode turned on (in-page editing of VF code), try turning it off temporarily.

Comment: Initially I had only tested with Firefox 26.  I've now tested with Chrome 32 as well with the same results.  Here's a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428043/Leads.JPG) from Chrome of the custom page.
I've disabled developer mode too.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  Have you looked at a debug log?

Comment: ok, now you've found me out.  I'm still learning Salesforce as we're just getting started with it.  How can I check the debug log for a visualforce page?  Is it somewhere in the logs section of the developer console?

Comment: The easiest way to get a quick log:  close the developer console (if open), and open a fresh developer console (this avoids occasional refresh issues).  Look at the tabs near the bottom, find the logs tab; it should be empty.  Refresh your VF page; this should generate a new log in the logs tab.  Look though it for anything that looks like error messages and post it here.  Debug log is a big topic, here's a place to start: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428043/MoreLeads.JPG) showing that I can see leads when I navigate to the regular leads page.

Comment: Aha - you're looking at the most recently view list, not the actual default list view.  I think I see your issue, and I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Nothing remotely error-like in the log.  It's almost as if it's a log of a completely empty page: [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428043/LeadsPageLog.JPG)  I tried creating a brand new page and pasting your VF code snippet into it but saw the same issue.  The screenshot was of the log captured from that new page.  Here's a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8428043/Test2.JPG) of that page in the browser with the VF code also visible.  Weird!

Comment: I pasted your updated code into my page and once I saw it working with Accounts, I change the controller to Lead.  I then saw the additional filter dropdown and changed it to a different one which properly rendered the leads!  Thanks Jason!